# Перевести Double в время

Tags: java, android

Есть значение часов

```
double hours = 60.769;
```

Как правильно перевести это значение в `HH:mm:ss` или `dd HH:mm:ss` или `HHH:mm:ss`

Comment: а какое время должно получиться из значения 60.769 ?

Comment: Опишите что такое 60.769.  В каком измерении?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
double hours = 60.769;
//Сначала Вы получаете целое количество часов

int _hours = (int)hours ; //60 часов
// дальше получаете количество минут с секундами после точки
double minute = 60*(hours - _hours); // 60 * 0.769 = 46.14 минут
// получаете целое количество минут, и т.д
int _minute = (int)minute; //46 минут
double second = 60(minute - _minute); 60 * 0.14 = 8.4 секунды
```

Comment: Что вы там курите? Откуда вообще такая запись?

Answer (score 2):

Алгоритмов перевода `double` во время могут быть разными. В Excel/VBA используется следующий алгоритм `(1.0=1 день)`:

```
double hours=60.769;

int days=(int )hours; //6 дней
int hrs=(int )(hours-days)*24; //18 часов
int mins=(int )((hours-days)*24-hrs)*60; //27 минут
int secs=(int )((hours-days)*24-hrs)*60-mins; //22 секунды
```

Проверяется легко - забиваем в Excel `60.769` и меняем форматирование на время, получаем `18:27:22`

Answer (score 1):

```
public class ConvertDoubleHourse {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double hours = 60.769;

        double days = hours / 24;
        int convertDays = (int) days;
        double hourse = (24.0 / 100) * ((days - convertDays) * 100);
        int convertHours = (int) hourse;
        double minutes = (60.0 / 100) * ((hourse - convertHours) * 100);
        int convertMinutes = (int) minutes;
        double seconds = (60.0 / 100) * ((minutes - convertMinutes) * 100);
        int convertSeconds = (int) seconds;
        System.out.println(convertDays + "d:" + convertHours + "h:" + convertMinutes + "m:" + convertSeconds + "s");
    }
}
```

Output: 2d:12h:46m:8s